# coordinate calculation program

Tags: windows, visual-c++, win32gui

I want to make a simple coordinate calculation program for windows :
[application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xi9t.png)

Can move X_Line (Red) and Y_Line (Blue) by left click mouse and show coordinates.

But I need help to make coordinates part and functions for this scenario.

Please help me to any part of the program that you can !?!

Thank for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and record mouse position, then send a paint message to paint at that coordinate.

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    static int xcoord = -1;
    static int ycoord = -1;
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        if(xcoord >= 0 && ycoord >= 0)
        {
            RECT rc;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);

            //draw horizontal line
            MoveToEx(hdc, 0, ycoord, NULL);
            LineTo(hdc, rc.right, ycoord);

            //draw vertical line
            MoveToEx(hdc, xcoord, 0, NULL);
            LineTo(hdc, xcoord, rc.bottom);
        }

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        xcoord = ((int)(short)LOWORD(lparam));
        ycoord = ((int)(short)HIWORD(lparam));
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) };
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszClassName = TEXT("classname");
    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

    CreateWindow(wcex.lpszClassName, NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        0, 0, 600, 400, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```